# What time zone does a FAT32 SD card record timestamps in?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, fat32

I understand that FAT32 formatted file-systems record timestamps for file modified times in [Local Time and not UTC time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068855/how-do-i-get-the-correct-modified-datetime-of-a-fat32-file-regardless-of-timezo).

However, if a device records a file to a FAT32 SD card using a datetime with no timezone*, what TZ does the SD card assume it is receiving?

My guess is either:

1. The SD card uses whatever timezone the SD card was FORMATTED in
2. OR - The SD card records the time (no TZ), and when that file is copied to a computer, the computer says, "*Ahh it's from a FAT32 card, must be in MY local time!*"

Bonus for canonical sources.

---

Edit: Preliminary testing says #2.

1. Format an SD Card as Fat32 and create a file at 12:45 am and eject
2. Change you computer timezone
3. Plug in SD card: file will show 12:45 am
4. Reformat in that new timezone, create a 12:50 file
5. SD card will read 12:50 no matter what TZ you plug it into.
6. HOWEVER -- if you change TZ while SD card is mounted, then the time will change...

So rather than call it Local Time -- it might seem more appropriate to call FAT32 file timestamps as "TZ Agnostic"

Comment: Re-written / merged with new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578155/python-os-path-getmtime-for-tz-agnostic-timestamps-originating-from-sd-cards  -- This one will be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the vintage of FAT32 and its predecessors the concept of adding a time zone to a file save or formatting was quite alien.

Similar for DOS,the time was the time so naturally it was local time.

I doubt that I could find a canonical source that was contemporary to those design decisions (or more accurately lack of design).

So to answer your question the file save time is most likely the local time, but later operating systems could decide to change the practice.
There is no standard way to store the TZ of the FAT32 device so you can discount that option

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung HMX-Q10 video cam which allows you to set timezone and DST in its setup.  Apparently it stores times as UTC on the SD card which is a major pain in the neck since I video edited a few files recorded solidly in the future when putting the SD card in my computer (which apparently expects local time).

I'm fuzzy about how to fix this since obviously one and the same SDcard may be used in several different devices.  I don't see much of an option other than lying about the time zone to the camera.  Which is sort of a nuisance since it precludes me from just flipping the "daylight saving time" indicator when, well, daylight saving time changes.

So there are devices storing in UTC in FAT32.  Which makes sense unless you are the only one that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Let us have a look on what a PC "shows" to me!

My System is "Windows 7 professional", just working with "Locales" of Germany. Today ist the 12-Sep-2022. The legal time zone is "CEST" (central europe summer time), or in other words "UTC +02:00".

It is 08:58 local time. I take a photo with my mobile phone (a Nokia E71, operating system "Symbian"), implicitly creating a file on the DS card (which is NOT the mobile phone's internal storage).
As expected, the mobile phone's "explorer" shows the "Datum" = 12.09.2022 and "Uhrzeit" = 08:58 . Fine!

My mobile phone is configured to automatically synchonize with the provider's time. Hence it switches automatically to (and from) daylight saving time.

Now I connect this mobile phone with my computer (USB, mode "Massenspeicher"). My computer sees a USB device connected to the computer.
The computer's file explorer tells me: the file system is FAT32, and the interesting file properties are:

- Aufnahmedatum:   "12.09.2022 08:58"
- Erstelldatum:    "12.09.2022 06:58"
- Aenderungsdatum: "12.09.2022 06:58"

For the non german readers:

- exif tag found inside the picture "when this photo has been taken"
- date and time the file had been created
- date and time of the file's last modification

Hence, creation time and time of last modification seem to be 2 hours in the past; it seems, that WINDOWS assumes this as data from the time zone "UTC +00:00").
The "exiftool", executed with parameters "... -DateTimeOriginal -FileModifyDate ..." shows, what we have seen before:
exif tag = "12.09.2022 08:58" and modification date = "12.09.2022 06:58".

Now I copy the file from the mobile phone to one of the computer's local disks, which has a file system of FAT32, too. The SD card stays in the mobile phone; it is NOT inserted into the computers SD card slot!)
The file explorer of WINDOWS shows me the properties of our interest:

- Aufnahmedatum:   "12.09.2022 08:58"
- Erstelldatum:    "12.09.2022 09:11" (when copied)
- Aenderungsdatum: "12.09.2022 06:58"
- "exiftool":      as before.

Now I cut all of the computer's network connections (network cable plugged off), because from now, I don't like interference with the "real" world, where the time continuously is "runing" as before.

I change the computer's date to 11-Nov-2022. Now, the WINDOWS system believes, that I'm 60 days minus 1 hour older, and the current time zone should be "CET", which is the legal winter time in Germany. Sorry, I only *assume* this detail. I did not really check the time zone in the computer!)

Now I let the file explorer refresh the displayed information.
Oops! The time stamps of the mobils phone's file are displayed as

- Aufnahmedatum:   "12.09.2022 08:58"
- Erstelldatum:    "12.09.2022 07:58"
- Aenderungsdatum: "12.09.2022 07:58"
- "exiftool":      as before!

The copy of this file, located on my local disk, now is displayed with

- Aufnahmedatum:   "12.09.2022 08:58"
- Erstelldatum:    "12.09.2022 10:11"
- Aenderungsdatum: "12.09.2022 07:58"
- "exiftool":      as before!

Now, I delete the copied file and copy it once more. I chose another target directory; hopefully there will be no interferences whith the deleted file.
This "new" copy is shown in the file explorer as:

- Aufnahmedatum:   "12.09.2022 08:58"
- Erstelldatum:    "11.11.2022 09:24" (system time when copied)
- Aenderungsdatum: "12.09.2022 06:58"
- "exiftool":      as before!

Finally, I set the system date back to the "real" world's 12-Sep-2022.

This experiment tells me, that the WINDOWS file explorer does not simply "show", what it finds in the mass storage, but "computes" the values before displaying it. (Remember, that the displayed values of "creation date" and of "modification date" had been changed after changing system date.)

WINDOWS does NOT modify the exif data. (They are part of the picture.)

How can I interprete what I've seen?
Does WINDOWS assume, that the mass storages (both "external" and "internal") hold time stamps, which are made "in" another time zone, and that this time zone is "UTC + 00:00" ?
Remember that "exiftool" in any case showed a modification date of "12.09.2022 06:58", without any chage after I manually had changed the system date.

Trying to understand, what is happening, I found the article about "File Times" in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times

"... The FAT file system records times on disk in local time. GetFileTime retrieves cached UTC times from the FAT file system. When it becomes daylight saving time, the time retrieved by GetFileTime is off an hour, because the cache is not updated. When you restart the computer, the cached time that GetFileTime retrieves is correct. FindFirstFile retrieves the local time from the FAT file system and converts it to UTC by using the current settings for the time zone and daylight saving time. Therefore, if it is daylight saving time, FindFirstFile takes daylight saving time into account, even if the file time you are converting is in standard time. ..."

The seniors under us remember, that MSDOS had a file system of FAT only and always stored time stamps in local time. Time stamps always had been displayed as stored. This "concept" was not really a good idea, because a world of international networks had not been anticipated. But locally, all seemed to be fine.

Really fine?

What about a nightly worker, who creates files with protocols of about what happens every 5 minutes, e.g. during melting steal? In autumn, when switching back from daylight saving time, he creates 12 new protocol files, which -- in the computer -- seem to be OLDER than files already having on the storage device. Each of the 3600 seconds between 02:00:00 and 02:59:59 seems to exist twice, when using local time. The German laws distinct it by naming it the "A-Stunde" and the "B-Stunde". But FAT32 cannot distinct it.

A steel company is not able to stop working for one hour (, because melting steel is a process which cannot be interrupted for an hour, only for several days, normally between christmas an new year). Hence, this company had to install another (solaris-, unix-, ... based) operating system.

Because the file system of FAT32 has no place for a time zone information per file, there is no chance to transform the semantic of time stamps to any other than the traditional "local time". (Or the usage compatibility must be broken.)

A long time later, NTFS had been invented, but this was too late.

Why are time stamps stored as "local time" on the one hand, but, on the other hand, NOW are converted to UTC while retrieving? Customers do not like this, even if they do not melt steal...

Therefore, in the future, I might continue my investigations with a modified experiment.

**These observations lead me to his SUMMARY**:

- **FAT32 does not store any time zone information.** You will find the time values, what the device decided to store. (My cameras always store a value of local time.)
- 'timestamp of last modification' and the 'timestamp of file creation' are part of the file system (here: FAT32).  The 'timestamp when the photo has been taken' is part of the picture file.
- WINDOWS 7 does not 'show' these 3 values, but **'computes'** it. The shown values obviously are correct only in some cases, but generally spoken they are not correct.
- If you need the true and unmodified values, then do **not** use WINDOWS' file explorer! To read this information, you may use the **"exiftool" (by Phil Harvey)**, which you can get here: https://exiftool.org/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But, the whole impressive **post ends on a tone of asking a question rather than answering the one at the top of this page**. Could you maybe add a summary, a TLDR, somewhere, to make more obvious what your solution is? I admit I did not read all the details, but with a contribution like that, I strongly recommend to help lazy people like me with getting the point of the post. Otherwise **the post risks being flagged as "not an answer"**, if more trigger-happy users get the same impression - correct or not. **See what I mean?**

Comment: Note, I do not ask you to add a lot of formatting. In the post itself you can just use some space for a few words of summary at the end, or maybe an abstract at the beginning. I only used formatting in the restricted space of my comment, in order to get the point across.