# Python: os.path.getmtime() for TZ agnostic timestamps originating from SD cards with different formats

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

*(Note: This may be a Superuser question, since it deals more with how a computer interprets a timestamp... but it has implications for all programming that deals with timestamps originating from an external device.)*

Problem construction:

1. Format 3 SD cards in FAT32, NTFS, and exFAT
2. Create a file on each of them using a TZ agnostic device (eg a camera, or scientific instrument where you set a time and date, but no TZ) at precisely 12:00:00
3. Copy those three files to a computer on California time (UTC-7)
4. Run python: `os.path.getmtime()` on each. Results will vary.

IT seems #3 is the critical step. Here is what I believe happens to the timestamps -- **can anyone confirm if this is correct?**

1. Since **FAT32** records timestamps in localtime, the computer assumes the file was created at 12:00:00 California time (UTC-7) and thus copies the file with a timestamp of 19:00:00 (UTC)
2. Since **NTFS** records timestamps in UTC, the computer assumes the file was created at 12:00:00 UTC, and thus copies the file with a timestamp of 12:00:00 (UTC)
3. Since **exFAT** is odd, it stores in UTC -- but *can include TZ offset in the master record* -- so all assumptions go out the window. **Does a computer assume UTC or UTC-7 as it copies an exFAT timestamp without TZ offset?**

---

Related:

[How do I get the correct modified datetime of a FAT32 file, regardless of timezone in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068855/how-do-i-get-the-correct-modified-datetime-of-a-fat32-file-regardless-of-timezo?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Much better question than your last one. :) I don't have a direct answer for you, but you might be able to infer some things from [here](https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/07/19/exfat-file-system-time-zone-concerns).  One option is that if the offset is zero, then the time is treated as UTC. The other is that if the "time zone bit" is zero, the time is treated as local time.  Perhaps someone else knows exFAT better and can answer with more certainty.